# how to convert a set into a list in firestore security rules?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

i need to get an item from a set returned from

```
resource.data.diff(request.data).changedKeys()
```

so, is there a way to get an item from a set, or turn a set into a list to get an item?

I don't need to compare any values, so i don't need `hasOnly()` or any related functions, i need to get one of the values in a set, any way to do this?

Comment: I have the same use case as you

Answer (score 4):

I raised a ticket to Firebase support to make Set's values accessible as soon as Set was added to the API. Still waiting...

The workaround I use is `request.writeFields`, which contains all the fields that are written to for a given create/update.

Note:

- `request.writeFields` is deprecated and may be removed (crazy in my opinion when there is no other workaroung available)
- For nested fields it will give you the full path for each field
  For instance if you update the following fields in your doc:

  ```
  {
    A              // UPDATED
    B: {
     BA
     BB            // UPDATED
    }
    C: {
      CA: {
        CAA        // UPDATED
      }
      CB
    }
  }
  ```

=> `request.writeFields` = `['A', 'A.BB', 'C.CA.CAA']`

Comment: did you get an answer yet?

Comment: @Stein. Still waiting :(

Comment: I submitted a request yesterday, it said that I will get an answer in 2 business days so we will see.

Comment: @Stein still waiting?

Comment: Requested .toList() method for Rules.Set last week, still waiting, not sure why this was not implemented from the beginning
im not sure why they keep this "its a free feature". No its not, firebase services are paid, this is an enterprise level product, add this sec rules on pay roll and stop complaining about being free, its not free! I paid for my DB, for my test suite, for android dev acc, for cloudFunctions, cloudStorage...

Answer (score 2):

The complete list of things you can do with [Set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Set) is in the linked API documentation.  Same thing with [List](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List).

As you can see, there are no element accessors available with Sets.  All you can do is check size and existence, and manipulate contents.

For Lists, you must know the index of the element to get something. If you don't know the index, then you can't access it.

Neither collection offers a function to "get an arbitrary, unnamed, unindexed item".

Comment: that last part sounds reasonable, but in my case, the set returned would only have one item, so if converted to a list, i would just need to get the item at index 0. do you think a function to convert a set into a list might be added in the future?

Comment: I don't know.  You can always file a feature request with Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @shmibbles my use case is identical to yours

Comment: You can submit a feature request here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features
I already submitted mine, but you can support this request.

Comment: if this is the case, then use a string field for best results, not a set. sets are designed to be an array of flags

Answer (score 0):

ok, there is no Set accessor, but if you know for a fact that your Set has exactly one value, or you want to access any value of the Set, and there is a list that includes this value, then you can use this approach to access the Set value (it should work even if you list is unsorted and has repeated values):

```
let s = 0;
let e = list.size() - 1;
let mid = 0; let firstHalf = false;


mid = int((s+e)/2);
firstHalf = list[s:mid].toSet().hasAny(inputSet);
s = firstHalf ? s : mid;
e = firstHalf ? mid : e;
```

just repeat the last 4 lines ~10 to 20 times, and either list[s] or list[e] will have  the value in inputSet

Comment: This misses the point: the all problem is that we do NOT know the values in the Set. Otherwise there is no problem at all